# Relationship errors while applying migrations - EF Core 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to model a scenario of consisting of 3 entities namely - `User`, `Post` and `Comment`

A `user` can author a `post`, and another `user` or the same `user` can `comment` on that post.

So the `User` entity can have multiple posts associated under it. And the `Comment` entity can have multiple comments associated with a single post by various users.

I am trying to apply a migration on my models using EF Core 5.0 but I am getting the error -

> Both relationships between 'Post' and 'User.Comments' and between 'Post.Author' and 'User' could use {'AuthorId'} as the foreign key.

> To resolve this, configure the foreign key properties explicitly in 'OnModelCreating' on at least one of the relationships.

---

Here are the model classes (User, Post and Comment) -

```
public class BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public IReadOnlyList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    
    public IReadOnlyList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Post : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }
    
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the context class -

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(x => x.Username)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<User>()
            .HasIndex(x => x.Email)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder
           .Entity<User>()
           .HasMany(u => u.Posts)
           .WithOne()
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder
           .Entity<User>()
           .HasMany(u => u.Comments)
           .WithOne()
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Author)
            .WithMany();

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.Comments);
          
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Author)
            .WithMany();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Can anybody correct the mistake and offer best practices to model this scenario

Comment: You need to add primary keys to your tables and add foreign keys to Post and Comment

Comment: @d0little Isn't `Id` primary key by default as I have moved that code to the `BaseEntity` class and won't Entity framework generate shadow properties for foreign keys ?

Comment: Something is missing in the picture. What is `Author` here `public Author Author { get; set; }`?

Comment: @IvanStoev `Author` is the navigation property to `Post` and `Comment` respectively, For `Post` it will indicate which `User` added that `Post` and for `Comment` it will indicate which user commented

Comment: I understand the property, but it it also is used like **type** (`public Author <--`) which I don't see.

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry it was a typo, its of `User` type

Comment: Ok, got it, the type is actually `User`. But I still cannot reproduce, not getting any error with the posted model, may be your `BaseEntity<T>` has members not shown here - something like `public User CreatedBy { get; set; }`?

Comment: Oops, wait, sorry, didn't notice the fluent configuration...

Comment: @IvanStoev, is there a better way to model this and re-write the configurations ?

Comment: Looks like you didn't "pair" navigation properties which form relationships correctly. You should have `User.Posts` <-> `Post.Author`, `User.Comments` <-> `Comment.Author` and `Post.Comments` <-> `Comment.Post`, i.e. 3 relationships, while you are configuring basically 6 relationships. Why don't you remove all these `Has` / `With` and let EF Core pair them by default, which worked for me?

Comment: @IvanStoev can you write an answer of the above comment in detail, I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You have to add UserId and PostId keys

```
public class Post : BaseEntity<int>
{

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int UserId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Posts))]
    public User Author { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : BaseEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Comments))]
    public User Author { get; set; }
    
   public int PostId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PostId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Post.Comments))]
    public Post CommentPost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No fluent configuration needed in this case ?

Comment: No, you should not need any

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Nope, getting error `The [InverseProperty] attribute on property 'Comment.Author' is not valid. The property 'User.Comments' is not a valid navigation on the related type 'User'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation.`

Comment: Try just  "Comments"

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I just didn't want to add constructors. But  you can use comments with contructors. Check my update.

Comment: Sergey can you explain your solution why the constructor and the `InverseProperty` attribute

Comment: I am sorry but you should ask EF core team. I even sent email about it to them before.  nameof(Post.Comments) doesn't work without a constructor. You can only use "Comments" in this case.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I updated my post. Now Post.Comments should work too